# What comes first—verb or adverb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives, infinitives, is-it-a-rule

Do you say,  to effectively communicate or would you say to communicate effectively. As ENL learner I get this confused quite often. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the context. Both types occur and there's no difference in meaning. But those are just remains of clauses; you need a full sentence to decide which one to use. That's what speakers do -- decide what to say next; at speed.

Answer (score 0):

"To communicate effectively" is the preferred option, as it avoids splitting the infinitive.

Splitting the infinitive means that a word intrudes between "to" and the verb (in this case, "communicate").

Comment: but of course the "rule" about splitting infinitives is hotly debated and often ignored. So don't be surprise to see it the other way around.  As in the original Star Trek intro:  ". . ., to boldly go where no man has gone before."

Comment: The rule is often debated, but most editors will correct split infinitives in text for publication if there is no advantage to the split. In the Star Trek example, there was an advantage of dramatic emphasis.